# Importing dates from excel or access to SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, date, import

I have a field of dates in an Excel that I am trying to import into SQL developer, but I either get an error message regarding the formatting or the date values come in their raw form from excel. Does anybody know how to import dates from Excel or Access into SQL Developer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores date in a different way. 
You can change format in sql developer Tools >Preferences >Database->NLS
I think you can change the format to "DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS" depending on your requirement.
http://www.jasonsdevelopercorner.com/?p=209